# New line in a TextBox with Return

Tags: wpf, xaml

i have a TextBox but if i hit RETURN i dont get a new line. Is there any special command for that? Google returns result with TextWrapping but that is not what i want

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean `TextBox` instead of TextBlock since it's not writable, You can acheive that by setting `AcceptReturns = "true"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want edit text in runtime you must use TextBox instead of TextBlock.

TextBox with multiline:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" />
```

You can also use [RichTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RichTextBox&referringTitle=Home) from [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/).